# Admob ads are not working on android but works in the unity editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I am creating an app with unity and I've been stuck for several days and I don't know what else to do. Ads were working fine until I got firebase into the project. I had some errors and deleted all the documents related to GoogleMobileAds and Firebase. I re-imported and the ads are not working.

**Ads work in editor but not android**. I am using test ads and it is the same code I use for another application where everything works fine. It is the same version of the Admob and Firebase plugin. I don't know if I deleted a file that I shouldn't or don't know.

I have put the appID of my application and I am using **test ads,** so it's not a mistake that I don't have any ads available yet.

I attach the errors of the logcat:

> E/Ads: Too many recently failed requests for ad unit ID:
> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712. You must wait a few seconds
> before making another ad request. E/Ads: Too many recently failed
> requests for ad unit ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917. You
> must wait a few seconds before making another ad request.
> E/sqlite3_android: [IKR-38846] ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK

I do not know why it is failing, it is the same code that I use for other applications and it works correctly.

Comment: Logcat errors are repeated all the time.

Comment: Do you have the permission to have internet access?

Comment: Yes, I have the permission in the projects settings and the Android manifest.

Comment: I got same problem, and I am using only admob plugin even test ads don't show, did you solve this problem?